# what is the difference between customer managed keys and customer provided keys in azure storage encryption

Tags: azure, encryption, azure-blob-storage

I am learning about Azure Blob storage using the Microsoft documentation.  When I came across this page

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/explore-azure-blob-storage/4-blob-storage-security

I found there are 3 types of key management in encryption

1. Microsoft managed key
2. Customer managed key
3. Customer provided key

I am unable to understand the differences between the last two.  Does the key provided by Microsoft in case of customer managed key?

Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you seen the table at the bottom of the link you shared?

Comment: Yes it says that 'Customer managed keys' are managed by both Microsoft and Customer and 'Customer provided keys' are managed by Customer.  But it does not clarify whether the key is provided by Microsoft for 'Customer managed keys'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, consider read these two articles from the Azure documentation. The [first one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/customer-managed-keys-overview) describes in depth how customer managed keys work, whereas [the second](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/encryption-customer-provided-keys) do the same for customer provided keys.

In a nutshell, when you use a customer manager key you are indicating a key stored in Azure Key Vault that you want to use to encrypt/decrypt data in a storage account.

Under the hood, this key will be used to encrypt/decrypt the key that in turn will be used to actually encrypt/decrypt the data in your storage account.

This process will be performed transparently every time you interact with your storage account.

It is very well described in the first article I cited:

[image: customer managed keys]

> 1. An Azure Key Vault admin grants permissions to encryption keys to the
>    managed identity that's associated with the storage account.
> 2. An Azure Storage admin configures encryption with a customer-managed key
>    for the storage account.
> 3. Azure Storage uses the managed identity that's associated with the
>    storage account to authenticate access to Azure Key Vault via Azure Active
>    Directory.
> 4. Azure Storage wraps the account encryption key with the customer-managed
>    key in Azure Key Vault.
> 5. For read/write operations, Azure Storage sends requests to Azure Key
>    Vault to unwrap the account encryption key to perform encryption and
>    decryption operations.

On the contrary, when using customer provided keys, you need to provide [the encryption key itself among certain metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/encryption-customer-provided-keys#request-headers-for-specifying-customer-provided-keys) you want to use for encrypting/decrypting data when reading or writing your blob data, when performing your requests:

[image: customer provided keys]

Again, now from the second document I cited:

> When a client application provides an encryption key on the request, Azure
> Storage performs encryption and decryption transparently while reading and
> writing blob data. Azure Storage writes an SHA-256 hash of the encryption
> key alongside the blob's contents. The hash is used to verify that all
> subsequent operations against the blob use the same encryption key.

> When a client creates or updates a blob using a customer-provided key on
> the request, then subsequent read and write requests for that blob must
> also provide the key.

> To send the encryption key as part of the request, a client must establish
> a secure connection to Azure Storage using HTTPS.

[This article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/customer-provided-keys-with-azure-storage-service-encryption/) could be of help as well.

Comment: So I understand in summary that in 'Customer managed keys', we instruct Storage to use keys (that may either be created by us or auto created by keyvault) from Keyvault and in 'Customer provided keys' we are providing the keys in every request header and it is not stored in Keyvault.  Thanks for simplifying the differences